# Regular expression to prevent adjacent repeating dashes

Tags: regex

In my asp.net application I am restricting allowed URL formats with regular expressions.I need to create regular expression which will not allow adjacent dashes in URLs

01)  allow URLs like

```
text1-text2.htm
text1-text2-textn.htm
```

02) prevent URLS like

```
text1--text2.htm
text1--text2-textn.htm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
/--/
```

If you found a match then it means the URL had two dashes.

Comment: Cant we restrict it within the regular expression itself ie. "not to match" if i have URL contains double adjacent recurring dashes? I have rewrite rules in database so can achieve the change by changing one database record.

Comment: No, I think that is not possible in the regex itself. You have to put a `NOT` operator in the matching code. I think for your scenario you have to use a 'positive match', look for answer below from Ray.

Answer (score 1):

`url.Contains("--")` will work for you, where the `url` variable is the url entered. Nice and concise, and you don't have to fuss with a RegEx.

Comment: `!url.Contains("--")` #pedantic :-)

Answer (score 1):

The negative answer posted by Aziz is best, but just for completeness sake here is a regex that matches the kinds of strings you wish to accept (as opposed to reject):

You want a string made up of zero or more of the following:

- a non-dash character, or
- a dash followed by a non-dash

A regex for this is

```
/^(?:[^-]|-(?!-))*$/
```

Now you can adjust the [^-] part to accept not just any character at all, but *only* those characters permitted in a URL (that is, if you wish to match *all possible urls except those with two consecutive dashes*).  To do this you will have to find the RFC that gives the URI syntax.  Will be somewhat tedious, which is why the negative solution with `/--/` combined with other checks is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Should be enough to search for the problem `-{2,}` and then do the negation. Ie as long as this regex (two or more dashes in a row) does not match, it's valid.

Or positive regex matching only urls you do want: `^([A-Za-z0-9]+-?)+\.htm$`

Comment: You should remove the caret and dollar sign from your regex.  You are suggesting that the OP look for a `--` appearing anywhere in the string then negating.  But with the caret and the dollar sign your regex matches ONLY an entire string of two or more dashes.

Comment: @Ray right, thanks, was already thinking about the other one.

Answer (score 0):

This will match a filename with 0 or more occurences of a single dash followed by a some word characters.

```
^\w+(-\w+)*\.\w+
```

Comment: Does fail for `test-test.test-test.html`.